# Find the volume by using triple integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, partial-derivative

> Calculate the volume of the contents of the bowl  $K$, which is given by $x^2 + y^2 \leq z \leq 1$.

$$x^2+y^2\leq z\leq 1$$

$$x^2+y^2=1\iff y=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

$$-1\leq x\leq 1$$

$$-\sqrt{1-x^2}\leq y\leq\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

$$\iiint 1~\mathrm{d}x~\mathrm{d}y~\mathrm{d}z=\iint\left(\biggl[z\biggr]_{x^2+y^2}^y\right)~\mathrm{d}x~\mathrm{d}y=\iint\left(-x^2+y^2)~\mathrm{d}y\right)~\mathrm{d}x=\int\biggl[y-yx^2+\frac{y^3}{3}\biggr]_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\int\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}-\sqrt{1-x^2}x^2+\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}^3}{3}\right)-\left(-\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{1-x^2}x^2-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}^3}{3}\right)=\int_{-1}^12\sqrt{1-x^2}~\mathrm{d}x-\int_{-1}^12\sqrt{1-x^2}x^2+\int_{-1}^1\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{3}$$

I don't know if I did right so far but as you can see I got something that is kinda hard to integrate and I'm pretty sure I wasn't meant to solve it this way so can someone please explain?

Comment: The original image had several sloppy mistakes. The TeXified version adds more typos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since:

$$
x^2+y^2 \le z \le 1
\quad \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \quad
0 \le z \le 1 \, \land \, x^2+y^2 \le z
$$

it follows that:

$$
V = \int_0^1 \text{d}z \iint\limits_{x^2+y^2 \le z} 1\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y = \int_0^1 (\pi\,z)\,\text{d}z = \frac{\pi}{2}\,.
$$

Comment: The title does say 'Find the volume using triple integral' though

Comment: Well yes OK, I mean I like your geometric argument for the xy integral but if you interpret the title as 'Find the volume by using three integrations' which is what OP was trying to do, then you haven't explained how to do that for the xy part.

Comment: My point was that, for a lot of sort of calculus 1 style exam questions about triple integrals I think you might get eg. '4/6, nice geometric argument but you needed to show working for the xy integral' for what you've written. It's not obvious that you need a triple integral to find this volume, it would be quite straight forward to do it geometrically without integration. I respect that you're not answering a calculus one exam, I'm not trying to be patronising I'm just pointing out for OP really

Answer (score 1):

You can use an substitution
\begin{align*}
x =& r \cos \phi\\
y =& r \sin \phi \\
z=& z.
\end{align*}
After that you will get an integral
$$\iiint_D \, dxdydz = \int_0^1 \, dr \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \int_{r^2}^1 r\, dz =
2\pi \int_0^1 (r-r^3)dr =2 \pi \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Alright so we are given the set

$$K=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2\leq z\leq1\},$$

and wish to find its volume $\operatorname{Vol}(K)$. The fact that we are dealing with the quantities $x^2+y^2$ and $z$ suggests a change to cylindrical coordinates might be useful. In particular, we change variables to

$$\begin{cases}
x=r\sin\theta,\\
y=r\cos\theta,\\
z=z.
\end{cases}$$

Observe then that the defining equation can be rewritten as

$$r^2\leq z\leq 1,$$

and so the bounds of integration will be

$$0\leq r\leq1,\quad 0\leq\theta<2\pi,\quad r^2\leq z\leq1$$

This gives us the volume as the integral

$$\operatorname{Vol}(K)=\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{r^2}^1r~\mathrm{d}z~\mathrm{d}\theta~\mathrm{d}r=2\pi\int_0^1r(1-r^2)~\mathrm{d}r=2\pi\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2},$$

where the factor of $r$ comes from the Jacobian which gets introduced by the change of variables.